# Inserting label to a Plot

Tags: plotting, configuration

I have the following figure

[image]

Given by the Following code

```
pic3 := Plot[0.7 + 0*x, {x, -0.5, 1}]
pic4 := ListLinePlot[
  Thread[List[0.8 & /@ Range[0, 1], Range[-0.2, 1]]]]

pic5 := Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}]]
Show[pic5, pic4, pic3, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

I would like to add 2 brackets one that said $\alpha$ between $(0,0)$ and the cut in $y$-axis and another that said $\beta$ between $(0,0)$ and the cut at the $x-$Axis. Is this possible ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{a, b} = MapThread[Graphics[{#, Disk[], White, 
      Inset[Style[#2, FontSize -> Scaled[.5]]]}, ImageSize -> 40] &, 
   {{Blue, Red}, {"α", "β"}}];

Deploy @ DynamicModule[{pt1 = {0., .8}, pt2 = {.8, 0}},
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Triangle[], 
    FaceForm[Opacity[1]],
    Locator[Dynamic[pt1, (pt1 = {#[[1]], .8}) &], a],
    Locator[Dynamic[pt2, (pt2 = {.8, #[[2]]}) &], b]},
   PlotRangePadding -> .2,  
   GridLines -> {{.8}, {.8}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, ColorData[97]@1]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For a different approach, beginning with version 12 you can use the **EXPERIMENTAL** function [`GeometricScene`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricScene.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Show[
 GeometricScene[
   {"O" -> {0, 0},
    a -> {0, 1}, b -> {1, 0},
    α -> {0, 0.7}, β -> {0.8, 0},
    α2 -> {1.5, 0.7}, (* 
    chosen outside the plot range *)
    β2 -> {0.8, 1.5}},(* 
   chosen outside the plot range *)
   {Triangle[{a, b, "O"}],
    InfiniteLine[{α, α2}],
    InfiniteLine[{β, β2}]}]
  ["Graphics"],
 PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 1.1}, {-0.2, 1.1}}]
```

[image]

Or for a dynamic scene

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  GeometricScene[
    {"O" -> {0, 0},
     a -> {0, 1}, b -> {1, 0},
     "α" -> {0, α}, "β" -> {β, 0},
     α2 -> {1.5, α}, (* 
     chosen outside the plot range *)
     β2 -> {β, 1.5}},(* 
    chosen outside the plot range *)
    {Triangle[{a, b, "O"}],
     InfiniteLine[{"α", α2}],
     InfiniteLine[{"β", β2}]}]
   ["Graphics"],
  PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 1.1}, {-0.2, 1.1}}],
 {{α, 0.7}, 0, 1, 0.025, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{β, 0.8}, 0, 1, 0.025, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]